# converting js into react autocomplete search input form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

quite new to this react thing but i previously wrote a simple js script for my own search input for autocomplete

```
$(function () {
    $("#search_item").autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source: function (req, resp) {
            var collected;
            $.getJSON("https://api.test.com/items/autocomplete?q=" + req.term, function (json) {
                console.log(json);
                resp(json.data);
            })
        }
    });
});
```

html

```
 <form action="/api/search">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="search_item" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." name="item_search_keyword">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" id="btnSubmit">Search!</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
```

trying to convert this into React with a simple input search bar but not so familiar with React. Possible if anyone can give me some help?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer to this is that you need to [convert your mind to React first](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html), before converting the code.

It is not just a small change to migrate code like that to React. React follows a fundamentally different approach, which is not compatible with your example. E.g. you should not [touch the DOM directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs).

Imagine you are not writing javascript / DOM anymore, but you are writing a different language (i.e. React) now.

As a vague direction for a solution: I guess you would create a React component like `<MyInputWithAutoComplete>`, which returns e.g. your `input-group`, and handles your autocomplete logic with a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).